# R 2.14.0 on MacOSX 10.7.2 Lion -- Quartz not displaying letters or numbers

Tags: macos, r, quartz-graphics

R does not show letters or numbers in Quartz when I plot(). Lines and points are displayed, just not text. x11() works fine.

Comment: Try providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) as well as the output from `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is could due to a corrupt font file. The Font Book.app program can be used to examine your current fonts and quartzFont() can be used to bring up the candidates for examination:

```
> quartzFonts()
$serif
[1] "Times-Roman"      "Times-Bold"       "Times-Italic"     "Times-BoldItalic"

$sans
[1] "Helvetica"             "Helvetica-Bold"        "Helvetica-Oblique"    
[4] "Helvetica-BoldOblique"

$mono
[1] "Courier"             "Courier-Bold"        "Courier-Oblique"    
[4] "Courier-BoldOblique"
```

You will typically find either a doubled entry with one of the contents blank or simply one of the entries with blank contents.